# SQL: How to sort overlapping groups efficiently

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique-constraint

I'm trying to make groups on a database with 10.000+ rows. 
I need to be fast and efficient, so I'm doing binary variables for each cluster. 
One, Two, Four, Five and Six is in Group1.

But 'Two' might also be in Group nr. 2, because of errors I cannot overcome because my dataset is from a webscrape. I try to sort everything in a unique way, but it's basically impossible not to do errors, if I wish to be efficient and fast.

```
ID   Title    Group1      Group2     Group3      Ungrouped
1    One      1           0          0           0
2    Two      1           1          0           0
3    Three    0           1          1           0
4    Four     1           0          1           0
5    Five     1           0          0           0
6    Six      1           1          1           0
7    Seven    0           0          0           1
```

**My idea for a sollution:**

1. Assign groups (one's) until everything is grouped one or more times.
2. Make a query for everything that has more than one group assigned (2, 3, 4, 6)
3. Manually decide which 1's to remove, until they only have one group assigned each.

It's actually a good idea to do the 3rd part manually, because it requires content analysis of the documents)

**My question:**

How do I specify, that I need to see everything with more than one group? Does it have something to do with constraints and unique values, or is there a more simple and obvious way that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your clusters are stored as integers, you can just do:

```
select c.*
from clusters c
where (cluster1 + cluster2 + cluster3) > 1;
```

I don't know what a "binary variable" is in SQLite.  Some databases do support binary flags, and you would need to convert the values to integers for the `where` clause.

Comment: This sounds perfect! Can you explain more about the 'c.*' and 'clusters c'? I'm new to SQL, as you've might have noticed.

Comment: `c` is a table alias.  It is not actually needed for this query.